# AndroidTextInput TypeError: expected dynamic type `boolean', but had type `string'

Tags: jsx, react-native

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Image,
    TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

var Login = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.heading}>My First App</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='User name'>
                </TextInput>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='Password'
                    secureTextEntry='true'>
                </TextInput>
            </View>
        );
    }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        padding: 16,
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: 30,
        marginTop: 10,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    input: {
        height: 50,
        marginTop: 10,
        padding: 4,
        fontSize: 18,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#112233'
    }

});

export default Login;
```

> Error while updating property 'secureTextEntry' of a view managed by: AndroidTextInput TypeError: expected dynamic type `boolean', but had type`string'
>   updateViewProp
>       ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:95
>   setProperty
>       ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:129
>   updateProps
>       ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:48
>   updateProperties
>       ViewManager.java:36
>   createView
>       NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:227
>   execute
>       UIViewOperationQueue.java:150
>   dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations
>       UIViewOperationQueue.java:923
>   doFrameGuarded
>       UIViewOperationQueue.java:895
>   doFrame
>       GuardedFrameCallback.java:31
>   doFrame
>       ReactChoreographer.java:136
>   doFrame
>       ChoreographerCompat.java:107
>   run
>       Choreographer.java:869
>   doCallbacks
>       Choreographer.java:683
>   doFrame
>       Choreographer.java:616
>   run
>       Choreographer.java:857
>   handleCallback
>       Handler.java:751
>   dispatchMessage
>       Handler.java:95
>   loop
>       Looper.java:154
>   main
>       ActivityThread.java:6123
>   invoke
>       Method.java
>   run
>       ZygoteInit.java:867
>   main
>       ZygoteInit.java:757

Please help me to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

secureTextEntry={true} instead of string, declared boolean type inside curly braces fixed

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    placeholder='Password'
    secureTextEntry={true}>
</TextInput>
```